# adding next and back arrows to jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, slideshow

I am sure this has been asked before, but i have tried a few other answers and none have worked thus far. Plus this is a two part question.

**1. I need to insert a back arrow and next arrow in my jquery image carousal.**

Here is the link to the current one: http://www.bmww.com/clients/index3/casestudies/cabrini_casestudy.html

I need the numbers to stay highlighted in correlation to the image even when the arrows are inserted. I would rather not change the transition effect unless for some reason i can not achieve this otherwise. Below is my code, but please let me know if you need anything else to answer my question.

here is my html code:

```
  <div align="center" class="slideshow" style="height:500px; float:none">

   <ul style="margin-top:-30px">
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_1.png" alt="lemon" /></li><!--MUST ALWAYS HAVE THIS HERE AND BE THE SAME IMAGE AS NEXT IMAGE-->
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_1.png" alt="lemon tea" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_2.png" alt="splashing lemon" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_3.png" alt="salad with lemon" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_4.png" alt="lemonade!" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_5.png" alt="sliced lemon" /></li>
  <li><img src="images/cabrini_6.png" alt="dripping lemon" /></li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="casenumbers" align="right" style="margin-right:10px">


 <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(0); return false"></a><!--MUST ALWAYS HAVE THIS HERE AND BE THE SAME IMAGE AS NEXT IMAGE BUT ALWAYS KEEP HIDDEN-->
 <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(1); return false">1</a>
 <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(2); return false">2</a>
 <a href="#" class="change_link"  onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(3); return false">3</a>
 <a href="#" class="change_link"  onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(4); return false">4</a>
 <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(5); return false">5</a>
 <a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(6); return false">6</a>
 <a href="cabrini_casestudy2.html" class="ex1" >    &#187; </a>

 </div> <!--end slideshow div-->
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
    <style>
    a{color: #666335;}
    a.clicked{ color: #D85D27;}
    </style>
```

and my script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
$('.slideshow').blinds();


    })
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.change_link').click(function(){
$('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
$(this).addClass('clicked');
});

    })
    </script>
```

**2. I dont know if you all see it when you click the example link, but sometimes when i do an odd scroll bar pops up and the entire list of images will show for a split second before everything is loaded. Is there a chunk of code i can add or a spinning wheel that would come up so it doesnt show until loaded fully and correctly?**

thanks in advance everyone!! Sorry, im still learning so i know this may seem like a simple or ridiculous question.

Answer (score 0):

In document ready:

```
$(document).keyup(
    function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == left)
            //decrement blinds
        else if(e.keyCode == right)
            //increment blinds
        else;//do nothing
    });
```

You'll have to look up the keyCodes for the right and left arrows.

Comment: ok here is the new link...i decided to use the following arrows: http://www.bmww.com/clients/index3/casestudies/cabrini_casestudy-test.html

Comment: sorry...so what can i do with that?

Comment: What this does is binds the event "keyup" for the entire document to that delegate function.  Essentially, any time a key is pressed in your document, it checks if the keycode matches, and performs the code (where my comments are) if it matches

Comment: I am getting an error on the         else if(e.keyCode == right)

Comment: you'll have to determine what keycode is right in the javascript documentation.  It can be different for different keyboard layouts

Comment: i inserted those left is 37 right is 39...and it then disables my slideshow showing all the images scrolling from top to bottom when insert this code.    Sorry :( i am still new to this

Comment: so @Pheonixblade9 my code is now: ` $(window).load(function () {
    $('.slideshow').blinds();
 
})
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.change_link').click(function(){
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');  
 
  });
 
$(document).keyup(
    function(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode == 37)
            //decrement blinds
        else if(e.keyCode == 39)
            //increment blinds
        else;//do nothing
    });

 
What do i put in the arrows for a class? if anything?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "what do I put in the arrows for a class".  Does this code work?

Comment: disregard the arrows for a class question...I simply was trying to figure out if i should specify a class on the arrows, and if so what the class would be named (just like the class for the numbers in the slideshow are named "change_link" telling the slideshow to work) and no the code did not work. It disabled the slideshow and instead showed all of my images instead of hiding them...not sure why though?